# Vim: Macro to insert a column at current cursor position

Tags: vim, macros

I have a variety of files that I would like to convert to comma separated variable (CSV) format.

For example:

```
      DATE     V1  COLOR SNOW FALL TEMPERATURE
2019-01-03 3.1415    red     33 mm          -2
2019-01-04 2.7182 orange     35 mm          -3
2019-01-05 1.6180 yellow     44 mm           2
2019-01-06 4.6692  green    120 mm           1
2019-01-07 1.4142   blue     51 mm         -10
```

would become:

```
      DATE,     V1,  COLOR, SNOW FALL, TEMPERATURE
2019-01-03, 3.1415,    red,     33 mm,          -2
2019-01-04, 2.7182, orange,     35 mm,          -3
2019-01-05, 1.6180, yellow,     44 mm,           2
2019-01-06, 4.6692,  green,    120 mm,           1
2019-01-07, 1.4142,   blue,     51 mm,         -10
```

I am able to manually do this in the vim *command mode* with the following:

`:%s/\%[column number]c/,/`

Where "[column number]" in my example would be 11 to insert a "," after the "E" in "DATE" on all lines of the file.

What I would like is to use a macro (preferably in my ".vimrc") so I could just place my cursor at a particular column and execute the macro rather than enter command mode. I am having trouble seeing how to get the cursor's current column value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as far as I understand you want something like this:

```
nnoremap <silent><F12> :execute '%s/\%' . col('.') . 'c/,/'<CR>
```